# How to update Document in MongoDB via Node.js and Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

My Document in MongoDb looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5550e710dad47584cbfe9da1"),
    "name" : "Serverraum1",
    "tables" : [
                  {
                    "name" : "Table1",
                    "nummer" : "1",
                    "reihe" : "2",
                   }
               ]
}
```

Post Method:

```
app.post('/serverraeume', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    db.serverraeume.update(req.body, function (req, res) {
    });
});
```

and the http post in angular controller:

```
$scope.addSchrank = function (serverraum){  
    $http.post('/serverraeume', $scope.table);
}
```

I want to update in the Document Serverraum1 tables. How can i push $scope.table in tables?

Comment: What's the object that's logged on `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: for example: { name: 'Test', number: '2', row: '2' }

Answer (score 0):

To update in the document `serverraum1` tables by pushing `$scope.table`, the mongodb **[update](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#update)** function your POST method should use the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator which adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) does nothing to that array:

```
app.post('/serverraeume', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var query = {"name" : "Serverraum1"}, // the query object to find records that need to be updated
        update = { "$addToSet": { "tables": req.body } }, // the replacement object
        options = {}; // defines the behaviour of the function
    db.serverraeume.update(query, update, options, function (req, res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```